# Mailcow smtp server no connection established

Tags: php, docker, nginx, smtp, phpmailer

I installed mailcow mail server with docker and added dns records (photo below). Nginx ,docker are running on the server. Problem with smtp prodocol or service . Trying connect smtp with php but waiting long time or dont connecting.
I tried send telnet to the ip like that:

## telnet 127.0.0.1 587

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.domain.com ESMTP Postcow
```

or to external ip

## telnet 1xx.xxx.x5x.x0x 587

```
Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xx...
Connected to xxx.xx.xxx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.domain.com ESMTP Postcow
```

For mailserver nginx configs following codes:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mail.domain.com


    location / {
        # auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        # auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/passwords/.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://1xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

And cloudflare dns records: [Cloudflare dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c78aG.jpg)

Where is problem ?

Comment: can you be more specific about the docker configuration: which commends do you use to run evereything? are there any Dockerfile's or docker-compose.yml? At a first look I would say that your nginx can't reach 1xx.xxx.xx.xx and you should add this information when you run the container.

Comment: Docker configuration is simple mailcow docker compose.yml . There is opened ports 25 587 496 or etc, for ips but not domain

Comment: I still think it would help your case to post most information. However, from what you say, my previous comment has the solution for you